java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
2024-05-31 22:47:36.939[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10452[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.s.e.d.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using output committer class org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode(NativeIO.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.mkdirs(ChecksumFileSystem.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:356)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(FileFormatWriter.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:792)
    at com.example.dubaiscala.spark.Sparktest.executeSparkJob2(Sparktest.java:50)
    at com.example.dubaiscala.spark.Sparktest.run(Sparktest.java:23)
    at com.example.dubaiscala.DubaiPolicawithscalaApplication.main(DubaiPolicawithscalaApplication.java:20)

But spark and Hadoop are running successfully .. spark v (3.5.1)standalone and hadoop 2.6.5
How to solve this ?

Make sure the correct hadoop.dll is in your PATH environment variable. for

hadoop.dll

file.
hadoop 2.6.5

And where to get this file if not available?
